# IPv6 Ubuntu - Not routing IPv6 to LAN

Tags: routing, ipv6

I'm trying to routing my ISP IPv6 to my LAN. Everything seems ok but clients (on Win7, Ubuntu) not reaching any IPv6 network. Something is missing but idk what.

Thanks.

ISP Router <-> eth1

eth2 <-> LAN

**Server config**
     Ubuntu 15.04 - 3.19.0-15-generic

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:00:c8:02
          inet addr:192.168.100.250  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe00:c802/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c802/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:400852 (400.8 KB)  TX bytes:231257 (231.2 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:00:c8:03
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:784 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:93975 (93.9 KB)  TX bytes:115547 (115.5 KB)
```

**radvd.conf**

```
interface eth2 {
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
        MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
        RDNSS 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844 {};
        prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 {
                AdvOnLink on;
                AdvAutonomous on;
                AdvRouterAddr on;
        };
        route ::/0 {
        };

};
```

**sysct.conf** (only net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1 wasn't working)

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.accept_ra=2
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra=2
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.accept_ra=2
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth1.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth2.forwarding=1
```

**Connectivity on server**

```
root@server:~$ ping6 www.google.com
PING www.google.com(2800:3f0:4003:c01::67) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4003:c01::67: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=58.7 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4003:c01::67: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=58.8 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4003:c01::67: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=58.8 ms
64 bytes from 2800:3f0:4003:c01::67: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=58.7 ms

root@server:~$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (64.233.190.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from gsademo18.google.com (64.233.190.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=56.2 ms
64 bytes from gsademo18.google.com (64.233.190.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=56.4 ms
64 bytes from gsademo18.google.com (64.233.190.99): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=56.5 ms
64 bytes from gsademo18.google.com (64.233.190.99): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=56.3 ms
```

**ip -6 mon** (during client browsing ipv6.google.com)

```
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
fe80::1 dev eth1 lladdr 44:55:b1:d5:05:76 router REACHABLE
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
fe80::1 dev eth1 lladdr 44:55:b1:d5:05:76 router STALE
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
fe80::1 dev eth1 lladdr 44:55:b1:d5:05:76 router REACHABLE
2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:5c5e:3a92:6239:64fd dev br0 lladdr 00:15:5d:00:c8:06 STALE
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
fe80::811e:d436:9ffa:ae76 dev br0 lladdr 00:15:5d:00:c8:06 REACHABLE
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
fe80::1 dev eth1 lladdr 44:55:b1:d5:05:76 router STALE
fe80::1 dev eth1 lladdr 44:55:b1:d5:05:76 router REACHABLE
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
fe80::1 dev eth1 lladdr 44:55:b1:d5:05:76 router STALE
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
fe80::1 dev eth1 lladdr 44:55:b1:d5:05:76 router REACHABLE
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
4: eth2    inet6 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:215:5dff:fe00:c803/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic
       valid_lft 86400sec preferred_lft 14400sec
prefix 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1::/64 dev eth2 onlink autoconf valid 86400 preferred 14400
Unknown message: 0000005c 00000044 00000000
```

**Win7 client ipconfig**

```
Adaptador Ethernet Conexão local:

   Sufixo DNS específico de conexão. . . . . . : xxxxx
   Endereço IPv6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:811e:d436:9
ffa:ae76
   Endereço IPv6 Temporário. . . . . . . . . . : 2001:xxxx:yyyy:aca1:5c5e:3a92:6
239:64fd
   Endereço IPv6 de link local . . . . . . . . : fe80::811e:d436:9ffa:ae76%11
   Endereço IPv4. . . . . . . .  . . . . . . . : 192.168.53.10
   Máscara de Sub-rede . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Gateway Padrão. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fe80::215:5dff:fe00:c803%11
                                                 192.168.53.250

C:\Users\windows7>ping -4  www.google.com
Disparando www.google.com [64.233.190.103] com 32 bytes de dados:
Resposta de 64.233.190.103: bytes=32 tempo=63ms TTL=48
Resposta de 64.233.190.103: bytes=32 tempo=58ms TTL=48
Resposta de 64.233.190.103: bytes=32 tempo=58ms TTL=48

C:\Users\windows7>ping -6 www.google.com
Disparando www.google.com [2800:3f0:4003:c01::63] com 32 bytes de dados:
Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
```

**EDIT1:**
Well my ISP gives me one public /64 address with dynamic prefix. My network uses radvd to allocate (curl script, to detect prefix changes). So, is it possible to routing? How could I do that?

Comment: Your internal interface eth2 is trying to use an IP address in the same subnet as eth1. This isn't going to work.

Comment: Either you need a shorter prefix such that you can allocate two different /64 to the two segments, or you need to bridge between eth1 and eth2. Somewhat related: http://serverfault.com/q/714890/214507